# How can I calculate the average, min, max, range for a cell from a dropdown and it changes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make price comparison between Dominos and Pizza Hut in Excel by making a dropdown list like this

[Dropdown list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfyv3.png)

And in the Dominos cell I'm trying to make it so that if you choose average price it shows the average price out of all the Dominos pizza prices which I've done a table on in another spreadsheet.

[Dominos price table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnFA9.png)

What I am struggling with is how does this cell [the one highlighted in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBomj.png) change it's price to whatever option you choose out of the dropdown.

I would appreciate it if someone helps me.

Comment: MAXIFS, MINIFS, AVERAGEIFS

Comment: I don't understand could you please explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: No sure what formula/calculation you want for "Range Price:" option

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the name of your reference sheets or their ranges, you will have to update the references in the formula below to meet your needs:

```
IF(Price_Type_Cell="Average Price:",
   AVERAGE(Dominoes_Price_Range),
   IF(Price_Type_Cell="Maximum_Price:",
      MAXIMUM(Dominoes_Price_Range),
      IF(Price_Type_Cell="Minimum Price:", 
         MINIMUM(Dominoes_Price_Range),
         IF(Price_Type_Cell="Range Price:",
            "enter formula for Range Price",
            ""))))
```

Comment: I'm not that experienced with Excel so I really don't understand what your solution is. What if I send my Excel file to you to see the problem?